# How can I edit description(not code) in Playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Here is the [playground](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/downloads/NewtonsCradle.playground.zip) that Apple provided as example.I can't edit titles and description but can edit codes.
[image]

So how can I edit it or how to switch to edit mode?Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode -> Editor -> Show Raw Markup[image]